# What do things move relative to?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, velocity, inertial-frames, observers

When someone says that a spacecraft in otherwise empty space is traveling at a constant velocity of 10 km/h (for the sake of convenience) then what is the reference point for which this measurement was made? You could say that it is simply a given point in space but space itself is relative. And what if I had two trains each traveling 3/4 the speed of light relative to the ground in opposite directions. If I were sitting on one of those trains what would I see when I passed by the other train? Would I see it trail faster than light? (Please forgive the "naïvety" of these questions, I am not trying to debunk relativity rather I am trying to find what I am misinterpreting)

Comment: Things move relative to other things, so if there are no other things, then one can't talk meaningfully about motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about the relativity principle is just that: all non-accelerating frames are equal, in the sense that no inertial frame is more "real" or "accurate" than an other inertial frame. If two frames are moving in a Minkowskian manifold with a constant velocity relative to each other, it doesn't matter which one you choose. No matter what, all the physical laws would be the same and there would simply be no difference between the frames. There is no such thing as absolute space. Things just move relative to other things.

Usually, when we say a spacecraft has an speed of 10 km/s, we are usually referring to its speed either relative to Earth or the lager body it orbits. For example, the orbital speed of Earth, relative to the Sun, is about 30 km/s.

Even seemly trivial things as *the order of events* are relative in special relativity (this is due to spacetime being non-Euclidean, though). Did the supernova SN 185, seen from Earth exploding in 185 AD, explode before Niel Armstrong set his foot on the Moon? Yes, in some inertial frames of reference this is actually the case. Are observes in such inertial frames "wrong?" No, they are equally correct in their observations as we are. Space and time just happen to follow the relativity principle and be non-Euclidean.

Regarding your trains: the velocity sum of of velocity $v$ and $u$ (which can be derived from the Lorentz transformation, see [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/veltran.html)) is $\frac{v+u}{1+uv}, c=1.$

If both trains are heading at a speed of $\frac{3}4$ of the speed of light, towards each other, the velocity sum would be $\frac{\frac{3}4+\frac{3}4}{1+\frac{3}4 \cdot \frac{3}4} = 0.96, c=1$ (I do not bother with signs here). **If you were sitting on one of those trains, you would see the other train rushing towards you at 96% of the speed of light.**

Comment: I think you mean $km/s$ rather than $km/h$. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne The Earth moves slower than a car. :)

Comment: Happens to me all the time. :-) Do you know that Jules Verne even wrote an entire science-fiction novel about getting units wrong? Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Purchase_of_the_North_Pole